# How do you print the conditional statement of an IfStmt in Clang?

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I'm developing a plugin for the clang compiler, and would like the conditional expressions of if statements in string form. That is, given:

```
if (a + b + c > 10)
    return;
```

and a reference to the IfStmt node that represents it, I would like to obtain the string "a + b + c > 10".

I suspect that isn't possible, but if anybody has any insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the condition part of the IfStmt, take its start and end location and use this to query the lexer for the underlying source code.

```
using namespace clang;

class IfStmtVisitor
  : public RecursiveASTVisitor<IfStmtVisitor> {
  SourceManager &sm; // Initialize me!
  CompilerInstance &ci;  // Initialize me!

  bool VisitIfStmt(IfStmt *stmt) {
    Expr *expr = stmt->getCond();
    bool invalid;

    CharSourceRange conditionRange =
        CharSourceRange::getTokenRange(expr->getLocStart(), expr->getLocEnd());
    StringRef str =
        Lexer::getSourceText(conditionRange, sm, ci.getLangOpts(), &invalid);
    if (invalid) {
      return false;
    }
    llvm::outs() << "Condition: " << str << "\n";
    return true;
  }
};
```

Input source:

```
bool f(int a, int b, int c)
{
  if (a + b + c > 10)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Output:

```
Condition string: a + b + c > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may want to try looking at the `printPretty` function defined in `Stmt` which `IfStmt` inherits from. That should hopefully get you close to what you want.